# Velocity, vorticity integral identity proof

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I obtained the following identity from numerical calculation but I cannot prove it:
$$\int_\mathcal{V} -\omega_i u_j  \frac{\partial\Omega_i}{\partial x_j} d\mathcal{V} = \int_\mathcal{V}\omega_i \Omega_j  \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} d\mathcal{V}.$$
$\mathcal{V}$ is a three-dimensional domain. $u_i$ is the velocity field, which is divergence-free,
$$\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_i}=0.$$
$\omega_i$ is the curl of the velocity ($u_i$). $\Omega_i$ is an arbitrary divergence-free vector field.
Furthermore, $u_i=0$ at the boundaries which means that
$$\int_\mathcal{V}   \frac{\partial(\omega_i u_j\Omega_i)}{\partial x_j} d\mathcal{V}=0$$
following from the Gauss divergence theorem. I tried to use this last relation to prove the first equation, but I failed. The following relations can be proved from the last and similar relations:
$$\int_\mathcal{V} u_j  \frac{\partial\omega_i}{\partial x_j} \Omega_i  d\mathcal{V} = -\int_\mathcal{V} u_j \omega_i \frac{\partial \Omega_i}{\partial x_j} d\mathcal{V}.$$

$$\int_\mathcal{V} u_i  \frac{\partial\omega_i}{\partial x_j} \Omega_j  d\mathcal{V} = -\int_\mathcal{V} \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} \omega_i \Omega_j d\mathcal{V}.$$

$$\int_\mathcal{V} u_i \omega_j \frac{\partial\Omega_i}{\partial x_j}   d\mathcal{V} = -\int_\mathcal{V} \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} \omega_j\Omega_i d\mathcal{V}.$$

From the numerical analysis, the first relation only holds if the vorticity ($\omega_i$) is the curl of velocity ($u_i$):
$$\omega_i= \varepsilon_{i,j,k} \frac{\partial{u_k}}{\partial x_j} $$

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: $\Omega_i = \sum_{j, k}\varepsilon_{ijk}\,\partial u_j/\partial x_k$.

Comment: This hold for only small omega. $\omega_i = \sum_{j,k} \varepsilon_{ijk} \partial u_k /\partial x_j$. $\Omega_i$ can be arbitrary. However, I failed using this relation.

Comment: My mistake, I missed $\Omega$ being an arbitrary divergence-free field.

Comment: I think I can prove it if $\Omega_i$ is *curl*-free, but I'm also having trouble figuring it out if $\Omega_i$ is divergence-free.

Comment: Sketch of proof:  Use the identity $$\vec{\omega}\cdot[(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{\nabla})\vec{\Omega} + (\vec{\Omega}\cdot\vec{\nabla})\vec{u}] = \vec{\omega}\cdot\vec{\nabla}(\vec{u} \cdot \vec{\Omega}) -  \vec{\omega} \cdot (\vec{u} \times (\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{\Omega})) - \vec{\omega} \cdot (\vec{\Omega} \times (\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{u})).$$The first term will vanish when integrated over a volume due to $\vec{\omega}$ being divergence-free; the last term vanishes because $\vec{\omega} = \vec{\nabla} \times \vec{u}$; and if $\vec{\Omega}$ is curl-free, then the second term vanishes.